# Angular 2 - change list item bg-color individually using ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-style

How can I change the background color of a list item generated using ngFor? I want to change the background  color of each list item individually when I click on one or hover it?

This is what I have now but it changes all of the line together when I click one line.

```
<ul class="list-group col-lg-6">
    <li href="#" class="list-group-item" [style.background-color]="whenClicked ? 'yellow' : 'none'" *ngFor="let recipe of Items "
     (click)="ChangeColor()">
      {{recipe.Title}}</li>

  </ul>
```

I've changed the code a bit according to suggestion of a member here. here it is now:

```
<ul class="list-group col-lg-6">
    <li href="#" class="list-group-item special-hover" *ngFor="let recipe of Items ">
      {{recipe.Title}}</li>

  </ul>
```

this is the css component:

```
.special-hover > li:active{
 background:#67EC32 
}
```

and this is the ts component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'recipeList',
  templateUrl: './recipeList.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipeList.component.css']
})

export class RecipeListComponent {
  buttonNew = "New Recipe";

  Items: ListItem[] = [
    { Title: 'Chocolate Cake' },
    { Title: 'RoastBeaf' }
  ];

  RecipeTitle:string;

  whenClicked = false;

  ChangeColor(){
      this.whenClicked = true;
  }

  addToList(){
    this.Items.push({Title: this.RecipeTitle})
  }
}

class ListItem{
  Title: string;
}
```

Comment: Does not CSS work for this?! `:active` and `:hover` should be enough to do this.

Comment: The :active seems to be what i needed. but will it work if the list is generated using ngFor like i did? Also can i applly the :active in my current code?

Comment: Sure! CSS codes will work with generated codes.

Comment: So correct me if i misunderstood what you suggest. i need to drop the method 'ChangeColor' and the [style.background-color] and just add a css file with a li:active with the backgreound - color i want?

Comment: Do you want different color for each list item? or they all will have just one color for the active, hover and normal status?

Comment: Same color. when i click on one row in the list i want it to change color. when i click another row i want that that row will change color and the previous row change back to normal

Comment: remove `[style.background-color]`, add a special class to `ul`, here is an example (add  `special-hover` class to `ul`):
here is your CSS:

`.special-hover > li:active{
   background:yellow
}
`

Comment: @M98 i've done what you said but it dont work. i remove the (click)="ChangeColor()" and the [style.background-color] from my <li . added a css component and put it in the ts component but nothing happend

Comment: if you can add style to your `li`, then you can use `:active` and `:hover` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track one by one li tags for clicked status:

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="list-group col-lg-6">
        <li href="#" class="list-group-item" (click)="whenClicked[i]=!whenClicked[i]" 
              [style.background-color] = "whenClicked[i]  ? 'blue' : 'green'" 
              *ngFor="let recipe of Items ; let i = index;trackBy: tracked">
              {{recipe.Title}}</li>
    </ul>
```

**Typescript**

```
  whenClicked = [false,false];
```

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8w41z?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

If you don't wish to put back the color, then `...(click)="whenClicked[i]=true" ...` is enough.

Comment: your solution is what i wanted! one click on one line to change that line color and another click to change that color back to the original color. And a click on each line individually to change each line color. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `whenClicked` variable is shared by all items in the list. You need to store state for every item separately. (Move click handler and `whenClicked` to the item object.) Something along these lines:

```
<ul class="list-group col-lg-6">
    <li href="#" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let recipe of Items ">
      <span (click)="recipe.ChangeColor()" [style.background-color]="recipe.whenClicked ? 'yellow' : 'none'" >{{recipe.Title}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To color on hover only, you can do it with css solely:
https://codepen.io/pbalaga/pen/zEKgwP

Comment: Was not better to suggest to use the CSS `:active` and `:hover` instead of writing another method?

Comment: It depends on what the OP wants to do in the click handler. If there is some additional logic, css won't suffice. Also :active will behave differently than changing state on click - it persists after mouse is released. Your suggestion may be sufficient in this case though.

Comment: @pbalaga What i would like to achive is that when i click on a single line of the list that line will change color. i didnt decided yet if i want another click to cancle that color change of to have it stay and when i click another line only that other line will be colored. But that's the basic idea